# Handling Remote Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I was reading how handling remote notification on developer apple guide. My questions are two:
what is the interpretation of the phrase

> The notification is delivered when the application isn’t running in
>   the foreground

isn’t running in the foreground covers background and not running or in the background state just. Based on the interpretation, the following sentence:

> the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification.

has a different sense.

The second question concerns the situation where I get two consecutive remote notifications: When I open the app in the method

> application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   or
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

I have information on all notifications or just the last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If your application is running, either in background suspended state or foreground, the method that will get called upon receiving a notification will always be `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`.
- If your application is not running at all, upon launch after receiving a notification, it will trigger `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and the options will be a `non-nil` object containing information about your remote notification.
- As far as I know, only the last notification info is available.

Comment: For the first response: also if i tap the icon app? I read all the documentation and there is no reference to what happens if you receive more than one notification.

Comment: Yes, if you tap the icon app or the notification from the system notifications UI will trigger same scenario. For second comment, as I said in my response, as far as I know, even if you receive more than one notification, only the info for the last notification is available. Not 100% sure about this one though.