# iOS - Content of push

Tags: ios, push, apple-push-notifications, payload

I googled a lot, but I can´t find the answer.

I'm trying to get the content / payload of a push notification while the app is in background.

The method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

doesn't work.

Comment: The method didReceiveRemoteNotification: is called? Or not?

Comment: it´s only called, when the app is in foreground while the push notification arrives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any `background mode` for the application (one of audio, gps or voip) the method `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` will be called not instantly but after the user press "Open" button bringing the app to foreground. If he or she decides to skip the notification you can do nothing about it, meaning you need to refresh the state when the application is back to foreground, you can not rely on the push notifications to update the data.

The better option might be to use the badge counter to track the changes, you need to calculate it on the server side. Then if the app in the foreground has the positive badge number you do update the data and reset the counter. However that's not perfect as there's no warranty the notification is delivered - you still need to check the badge counter (or you can say to check the number of changes) manually.

Comment: in -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo i will recieve a array with all pushs, but that does only work, if the app is already in foreground. when the user presses the homebutton and than recieves a push and than starts the app. i´ll never get the pushs

Comment: According to the documentation either this method or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (with the payload stored at options with the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)`) is called as the result of received (opened if the app wasn't running) push notification.

Comment: Read `Handling Local and Remote Notifications` section of Apple docs to find what you are doing wrong: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: i found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335762/handling-remote-notifications