# Remote Notification 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' method not called

Tags: ios, push-notification, appdelegate

Target: 7.0 and UP

Testing on: iPhone6 Device

I have been testing Regular Push Notifications (Remote).

I have discovered that if a user clicks on the app icon -- the "applicationDidFinishLaunching:" method is never called.

I have been reading and re-reading the guide on "Handling Local and Remote Notifications" and to confirm that I understood everything referred to: [Handling Remote Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335762/handling-remote-notifications)

It says If a user taps the default button in the alert or taps (or clicks) the app icon, then the app should call its delegate "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method. And if its a remote notification, it should call "application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:".

Neither one of these methods get called if I click on the app icon.

The only method that does get called is `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

I do have a storyboard file. So the way it loads:

--> navigation controller --> table view controller --> so on

Am I supposed to somehow set the appDelegate in the storyboard file?

I have done a lot of research and so far I have had no luck.

My push alerts do come through so I know that it works. I just haven't been able to determine why these other methods are not being called when the user clicks on the app icon.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: The `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is only called if an app is not suspend or running in the background. `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is for fetch data push notification only. The `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called if the user brings an app to the foreground by clicking on the notification.

Comment: Yeah, but in Apple's documentation they say that if a user clicks on the default button in the alert or taps (or clicks) on the app icon then it will call those methods. But, I've done a ton of testing and those methods never get called. I thought that if the application was running in the background that the method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" wouldn't get called.. but the documentation made it seem like it should.

Comment: @SandyD. could you point where Apple says that, I don't remember. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is only called if your app is not in a suspended state, for instance after is killed by user or system. rckoenes is right

Comment: @Andrea: I have been reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4

I assumed that the line about clicking on the app icon meant for either (running in background or not running at all). I had implemented silent notifications instead to get my data if a user chose the icon instead because I could never get this to work. But, I wanted to make sure that there was no way to get this data. Silent notifications won't work for me b/c of throttling.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution if you want to handle when a user clicks on the app icon is to either A.) set up silent notifications or B.) Set up something on your server so that you can make a request to it to find out if there was a new update.